# HTML bootstrap collapse doesnt working at first button press properly

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Can you help me with that bootstrap and javascript collapse please?
I have two collapse cards. The first should card be visible than you click on the link. After the click should show next card and the first should disappear.
It is functional but at the first click there are both cards. Thats fix after the second click. Thank u for your help.

HTML:

```
<div class="card text-center">
      <div class="card-header ">           
             <a class="nav-link" id="spust" href="#">Kontaktní formulář</a>

      </div>
   <div id="kontakty">     
   </div>

   <div class="collapse" id="konform">
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var collapsestate = false;
jQuery('#spust').on("click",function(e) {

if (collapsestate == false){

      $('#kontakty').collapse('hide');
      $('#konform').collapse('show');
      collapsestate = true;
}
else{
    $('#konform').collapse('hide');
    $('#kontakty').collapse('show');
    collapsestate = false;
}
console.log(collapsestate);
});
```

Comment: you are simply missing to close the on function in javascript

Comment: it is completed I just copied it without end brace sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this snippet code... I think this snippet is as per your requirements.

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var collapsestate = false;
            $('#kontakty').collapse('show');
            
            $('#spust').on("click",function(e) {

            if (collapsestate == false){

                $('#kontakty').collapse('hide');
                $('#konform').collapse('show');
                collapsestate = true;
            }
            else{

                $('#kontakty').collapse('show');
                $('#konform').collapse('hide');
                collapsestate = false;
            }
            console.log(collapsestate);
        });

        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header ">           
            <a class="nav-link" id="spust" href="#">Kontaktní formulář</a>
        </div>
        <div id="kontakty"> 
            abcd   
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="konform">
            1234
        </div>
    </div>
  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add "display:none" to make 'kontakt' invisible before click it:

```
<div id="kontakty" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Comment: Since inline css/js is strongly discouraged, you could *also* show how to do this using style tags, and also how to do it using jQuery (and where to put the `.hide()` code - i.e. as the 2nd line in his js)

Comment: I want to make kontakt card as the only visible card before click, after click should be visible only the second card. And I want be able to repeat that action more times. Problem is at the first click because kontakt card do not hide from unknown reason.